# How to merge 2 images (one with shape) and make it transparant in an Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

I have 2 images of a pirate, one with the shape, and one with the pirate itself. I want to merge that 2 pictures together to create an image with transparant borders to use into my canvas. The only problem is i cant find a way to actually manage this.

The images itself are naturally not transparant at all, so i played with the Composite options in javascript, to try to make it transparant with the 'lighter' option, but i cant find a way to get rid of the white borders around the image.

This is a part of the code i currently have:

```
ctx.canvas.width = pirate_shape.width;
ctx.canvas.height = pirate_shape.height;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, pirate_shape.width, pirate_shape.height);

// Draw the shape in reversed colors so i can draw the picture inside the shape.

ctx.drawImage(pirate_shape, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='difference';
ctx.fillStyle='white';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, pirate_shape.width, pirate_shape.height);

// Draw the pirate itself
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
ctx.drawImage(pirate, 0, 0);
```

The complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/0kbj2Leg/

The result im trying to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zZwU.jpg

The 2 images i used:

(the pirate)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO09b.jpg

(the shape)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2PRn.jpg

---

Do you guys know maybe an way to get that result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use compositing, not blending.

To do this, you need transparency. Your images don't contain any.

Since your border image is black and white, there is actually an easy way in modern browsers to convert the white to transparent pixels: svg filters.

Once done, we can use compositing to achieve our goal.

```js
// just the assets loader
(async () => {
const [face, border, back] = await Promise.all(
  [
    'https://i.imgur.com/8R1qutU.png',
    'https://imgur.com/qemOzU2.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png'
  ].map(url => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return new Promise(res => {
      img.onload = e =>  res(img);
    });
  })
);


const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

// generate the border transparency based on luminance
// use the brightness to control how much red we keep
ctx.filter = 'brightness(180%) url(#trans)';
ctx.drawImage(border, 10, 10);
ctx.filter = 'none';

await wait(1000); // only for demo

// draw the face only where we already have the border drawn
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
ctx.drawImage(face, 10, 10); 

await wait(1000); // only for demo

// draw the background behind
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
ctx.drawImage(back, -100,0, 400,300);

// reset
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

})();

// only for demo, so we can see the different steps
function wait(ms) { return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)) }
```

```css
canvas {  
  background-color: ivory;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<svg style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;z-index:-1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="trans">
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Now, it would obviously be a lot easier if you can prepare your assets correctly from the beginning:

```js
// just the assets loader
(async () => {
const [face, border, back] = await Promise.all(
  [
    'https://i.imgur.com/8R1qutU.png',
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/778ZM.png', // already wth transparency
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png'
  ].map(url => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return new Promise(res => {
      img.onload = e =>  res(img);
    });
  })
);


const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(border, 10, 10);

// draw the face only where we already have the border drawn
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
ctx.drawImage(face, 10, 10); 

// draw the background behind
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
ctx.drawImage(back, -100,0, 400,300);

// reset
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

})();
```

```css
canvas {  
  background-color: ivory;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

But you could probably even get rid of the border image entirely by drawing a shadow over a well prepared pirate image:

```js
// just the assets loader
(async () => {
const [face,back] = await Promise.all(
  [
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hzcD.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png'
  ].map(url => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return new Promise(res => {
      img.onload = e =>  res(img);
    });
  })
);


const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

// draw the background
ctx.drawImage(back, -100,0, 400,300);

// draw the face with a shadow
ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
ctx.shadowColor = "red";

// little hack to make shadow more opaque

// first move your shadow away from what you wish to draw
ctx.shadowOffsetX = face.width + 10; // + 10 because we'll draw the last one at x:10
ctx.shadowOffsetY = face.height + 10;

// now draw your shape outside of the visible area
ctx.drawImage(face, -face.width, -face.height);
await wait(1000); // just for demo
ctx.drawImage(face, -face.width, -face.height);
// we now have to shadows overlapping but not our shape
await wait(1000); // just for demo
// reset the shadowOffset
ctx.shadowOffsetX = ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
// adn draw the last one
ctx.drawImage(face, 10, 10);

ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
ctx.shadowColor = 'transparent';
})();

// only for demo, so we can see the different steps
function wait(ms) { return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)) }
```

```css
canvas {  
  background-color: ivory;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly where i was looking for :)

Comment: Can't believe this post received positive votes.